# varImp não reconhece modelo de gradient boosting produzido pelo caret quando eu aplico pesos à target

Tags: r, aprendizagem-de-máquina, caret

Produzi um modelo de gradient boosting com o pacote `caret` e apliquei pesos à variável target. Quando eu chamo a função `varImp` no modelo ela retorna o erro:

```
Error in xgb.model.dt.tree(feature_names = feature_names, text = model_text_dump, : Non-tree model detected! This function can only be used with tree models.
```

Se eu não aplicar os pesos, o `varImp` funciona normalmente. Por que ele não identifica a minha árvore?

Meu código:

```
set.seed(123)

model_weights <- ifelse(modelo_df_sseg$FATALIDADES == 1,
                        yes = (1/table(modelo_df_sseg$FATALIDADES)[2]) * 0.5,
                        no = (1/table(modelo_df_sseg$FATALIDADES)[1]) * 0.5
                        )

model <- train(
  as.factor(FATALIDADES) ~.,
  data = modelo_df_sseg, 
  method = "xgbTree",
  trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
  weights = model_weights
  )
varImp(model)
```

**EDIÇÃO 04/09/2020**

No stack overflow em inglês me orientaram a utilizar wts ao invés de weights, mas agora a mensagem de erro que aparece para mim é:

```
Error in nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, : argumento formal "wts" corresponde a múltiplos argumentos especificados
```

Segue um código que vocês possam testar em suas próprias máquinas:

```
library(caret)
library(carData)

set.seed(123)

basex <- Arrests

model_weights <- ifelse(basex$released == 2,
                        yes = (1/table(basex$released)[2]) * 0.5,
                        no = (1/table(basex$released)[1]) * 0.5
                        )

y = basex$released
x = basex
tc = trainControl("cv", number = 10)

mtd = "xgbTree"
model <- train(
  x, 
  y, 
  method = mtd,
  trControl = tc, 
  wts = model_weights,
  verbose = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: Você precisa compartilhar o código todo e o dataset para quem for testar conseguir fazer a reprodução do erro. Mas o erro que está descrito é que você está tentando chamar a função passando como parametro algo que ele não espera, a função espera um modelo de árvore.

Comment: Também postei uma versão da pergunta no stack americano e me disseram pra fazer com wts ao invés de weights. vou adicionar na minha pergunta com uma base de exemplo em que você pode testar na sua máquina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução encontrada no stackoverflow em inglês. Segue código exemplo:

```
set.seed(123)

basex <- Arrests

model_weights <- ifelse(basex$released == "Yes",
                        table(basex$released)[1]/nrow(basex),
                        table(basex$released)[2]/nrow(basex))

dummies <- dummyVars(released ~ ., data = basex)
x <- predict(dummies, newdata = basex)
y <- basex$released
folds <- createFolds(basex$released, 10)
tc <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                   number = 10,
                   summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                   index = folds, #predefined folds
                   classProbs = TRUE) #needed for twoClassSummary

mtd <- "xgbTree"

model <- train(x = x, 
               y = y, 
               method = mtd,
               trControl = tc, 
               weights = model_weights,
               verbose = TRUE,
               metric = "ROC")

varImp(model)

model$results %>%
  filter(ROC == max(ROC))
```